# "ORTED_CMD_PROCESSOR: STUCK IN INFINITE LOOP - Aborting"

Tags: mpi, eigen

When doing the final reduction (summation of a bunch of matrices in my program), as follows

```
struct Tomo {

    typedef Eigen::Matrix<int, HISTOGRAM_BOXES, HISTOGRAM_BOXES, Eigen::RowMajor> HistoMtx;

    HistoMtx exp_val;
    HistoMtx u;
```

[...]

```
struct buffer_set {
    Tomo * X;
    Tomo * Y;
    Tomo * Z;
} buffers[2];
```

[...]

```
if(rank == 0){
    /* MASTER NODE */
    for(int source=1; source<size; source++){
        printf("Reducing from %i\n", source);

        for(int i=0;i<env_count;i++){
            MPI_Recv(buffers[1].X[i].exp_val.data(), buffers[1].X[i].exp_val.size(), MPI_INT, source, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(buffers[1].Y[i].exp_val.data(), buffers[1].Y[i].exp_val.size(), MPI_INT, source, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(buffers[1].Z[i].exp_val.data(), buffers[1].Z[i].exp_val.size(), MPI_INT, source, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            MPI_Recv(buffers[1].X[i].u.data(), buffers[1].X[i].u.size(), MPI_INT, source, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(buffers[1].Y[i].u.data(), buffers[1].Y[i].u.size(), MPI_INT, source, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(buffers[1].Z[i].u.data(), buffers[1].Z[i].u.size(), MPI_INT, source, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        }

        merge_buffers(0, 1);
    }

    WriteH5File("h5file.h5", 0);

}else{
    /* SLAVE NODES */
    for(int i=0;i<env_count;i++){
        MPI_Send(buffers[0].X[i].exp_val.data(), buffers[0].X[i].exp_val.size(), MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(buffers[0].Y[i].exp_val.data(), buffers[0].Y[i].exp_val.size(), MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(buffers[0].Z[i].exp_val.data(), buffers[0].Z[i].exp_val.size(), MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Send(buffers[0].X[i].u.data(), buffers[0].X[i].u.size(), MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(buffers[0].Y[i].u.data(), buffers[0].Y[i].u.size(), MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(buffers[0].Z[i].u.data(), buffers[0].Z[i].u.size(), MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
```

the pbs_mom process dies. When running the program in an interactive session, I find the following in my logs

```
[compute-35-3.local:01139] [[33012,0],2] ORTED_CMD_PROCESSOR: STUCK IN INFINITE LOOP - ABORTING

[compute-35-3:01139] *** Process received signal ***
```

I don't understand what this means or what would trigger it. It seems quite internal to OpenMPI.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the underlying network or something else that might require administrator attention.  For example:

http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2010/08/14130.php

http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/petsc-users/2013-August/018470.html